# Right-to-left eclipse appears when developing a plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, right-to-left

My Windows machine is in a region using right-to-left text direction. However, eclipse behaves in a left-to-right manner, e.g. with menus and text alignment on the left side. This is good as it is my preferred layout.

However, I am developing an eclipse plugin and whenever I launch my plugin as an "eclipse application", a new eclipse instance is opened with my plugin in it, and that new instance is presented in right-to-left layout.

Since I prefer the left-to-right layout, is there any way to configure the created eclipse instance to behave like that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -nl flag to specify the locale. See http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm. You can use that flag in your run configuration.